# What are some good alternative serialization formats?

Tags: xml, serialization, yaml

I have used XML in the past, but it is very verbose and clunky. We are currently using YAML, but I am finding that most developers have alot of trouble with the whitespace. Is there a YAML like format that is whitespace insensitive, but not as verbose as XML?

Comment: For what kind of data? And what use cases?

Comment: Some configuration, some object serialization for later use. The biggest issue is people modifying the yaml and adding whitespace (tabs) that then break the file. I can usually fix it, but I don't want to hand hold the others.

Comment: That's really interesting: YAML indentation makes it easy to read, but harder to write.  The same problem comes up with Python and make.  But with Python, you get a syntax error as soon as you compile - which might not happen with data files.  Perhaps one solution is a simple YAML syntax-checker for developers to use?  ie. that does absolutely nothing but check the syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't *have* to use the whitespace syntax in [YAML](http://YAML.Org/). All the datastructures also have non-whitespace alternatives, e.g. sequences `[1, 2, 3]` and maps `{ key: value, k: v }`. This is called [*flow style*](http://YAML.Org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2790088) as opposed to *block style*.

An alternative might be [JSON](http://JSON.Org/), which is actually a subset of YAML. It's basically YAML without block style and without extensibility.

Standard Lisp list syntax (list delimited by parentheses, elements separated by whitespace) is also a very nice format.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend checking out [TOML](https://github.com/mojombo/toml). Not case-insensitive, but nevertheless fixing all the problems with complexity in YAML.